# How can I write the "word" representation of an integer to a file in Java?

Tags: java, io, integer, byte, dataoutputstream

Here is a sample code:

```
File x = new File("garbage.byte");
x.createNewFile();

int i1 = 5;

DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(x));
dataOutputStream.write(i1);
dataOutputStream.flush();
dataOutputStream.close();
```

When I open the file **garbage.byte** in a hex viewer I will see:

```
00000101
```

which is ok.

My question is, what if I have an integer greater than 256?

How can I write 2 bytes into the file which will represent the integer greater than 256?

Comment: API will write long/short/String etc. Just have a look at API and try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
dataOutputStream.writeShort(i1);
```

to write i1 as a `short` (which is 2 bytes).

Similarly, there is `writeInt` (4 bytes) and `writeLong` (8 bytes). `DataOutputStream` has a method to write each of Java's primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`writeInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29) method of [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html). It will fit for an integer. You can use the following code snippet -

```
   try{   

        fos = new FileOutputStream("c:\\test.txt");        
        dos = new DataOutputStream(fos); 
        dos.writeInt(i1); 

   }catch(Exception e){
       //handle exception
   }finally{
       if(fos!=null)
           fos.close();
       if(dos!=null)
           dos.close();
   }
```

Hope it will help.
 Thanks a lot